# Display taxonomy terms in node_content-type.tpl and node_content-type--teaser.tpl

Tags: theming, taxonomy-terms

i'm on drupal 7.x, i have simple terms without subterms to display on my custom content type (node and teaser templates).

It should be easy to do, but i don't understand how to display them, i tried many things like :

```
$term = current($node->taxonomy);
echo '<div class="some-class">' . $term->name . '</div>';
```

or

```
<?php print render($content['field_tags']); ?>
```

or

```
<?php   $term = current($node->taxonomy);
    print  '<div id="prod-cont-my" class="my-'.$term->name.'">' ;
   ?>
```

and other, and i get no result.

Could someone give me a clue ? thanks in advance !

Comment: Might be a stupid question, but are your terms set to display in the content type? (admin/structure/types/manage/content-type/display)

Comment: what do you mean by set to display ? in this adress i have a field named categories who's not hidden and have a label form, i suppose this is what you wanted to know ^^ (edit : and in the options of categories i have nothing of these options checked : "show entity labels regardless of user access" and "Link label to the referenced entity")

Comment: That is what I was asking. TBH, the `print render($content['field_tags']);` should give you what you want (using the display settings from the above). Are you definitely using the correct field name (field_tags)? Have you cleared the cache? You could put some debug code like "I'M HERE" to check the template is being picked up. The field should print by default  unless you either hide it at the address above, or exclude it in the template. Its probably worth using the default template to check the data first.